# Python in PowerBI

Tags: python, powerbi

In August 2018, Microsoft has launched the Python integration in PowerBI [Python Integration - PowerBI](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-bi-python-scripting-installation-of-python/).
I have enabled the python scripting in it. My question is:

1. Can i call the libraries like numpy,scipy, pandas, tensorflow and visualize data it in Powerbi itself.
2. If yes, then please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call libraries that you have installed on your local machine (provided you import them) or if you're talking about the Power BI service (online), you can use any of the many libraries they support.

Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for broad guides for how to do things, but here's an example from Microsoft's Power BI blog:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/pythonblogepisode1/

Answer (score 0):

you can check this example :
1. import Py graphic object
2. copy/paste python code (prerequesite : have python and adhoc lib locally if you use Powerbi desktop)

```
import matplotlib as mplb
import pandas as pd

mplb.use('Agg')
plt = mplb.pyplot
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/.../dataset.csv', sep='|')
plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,4.5))
ax = plt.gca()
dataset.plot(kind='line',x='whatever_x',y='whatever_y',ax=ax) 
plt.show()
```